# How do I find the value which encompasses the most data points when combined with a tolerance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an array `times` containing arrays of timestamps that can be generated as follows.

```
a = [
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:47", "15:50:46", "15:50:47"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:46", "15:50:45", "15:50:45"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:46", "15:50:47", "15:50:47", "15:50:50", "15:50:49",
   "15:50:49", "15:50:48", "15:50:48", "15:50:50", "15:50:53", "15:50:52",
   "15:50:53", "15:50:51", "15:50:52", "15:50:51"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:46", "15:50:45", "15:50:45", "15:50:48", "15:50:48",
   "15:50:49", "15:50:49", "15:50:47", "15:50:47", "15:50:51", "15:50:52",
   "15:50:52", "15:50:51", "15:50:50", "15:50:50"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:47", "15:50:51", "15:50:47", "15:50:50", "15:50:51",
   "15:50:50", "15:50:46", "15:50:49", "15:50:48", "15:50:48", "15:50:44",
   "15:50:49", "15:50:44", "15:50:45", "15:50:45"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:46", "15:50:45", "15:50:45", "15:50:42", "15:50:43",
   "15:50:42", "15:50:44", "15:50:43", "15:50:48", "15:50:49", "15:50:49",
   "15:50:48", "15:50:44", "15:50:47", "15:50:47"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:47", "15:50:46", "15:50:43", "15:50:47", "15:50:45",
   "15:50:44", "15:50:44", "15:50:48", "15:50:48", "15:50:45", "15:50:41",
   "15:50:43", "15:50:42", "15:50:42"],
  ["15:50:46", "15:50:47", "15:50:47", "15:50:43", "15:50:43", "15:50:42",
   "15:50:46", "15:50:44", "15:50:45", "15:50:40", "15:50:40", "15:50:41",
   "15:50:45", "15:50:42", "15:50:44", "15:50:41"],
  ["15:50:29", "15:50:26", "15:50:29"]
] 

require 'time'

times = a.map { |b|
  b.map { |s| DateTime.strptime('2019-01-24 '+s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_time } }
  #=> [[2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000,
  #     2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000]
  #     ...
  #    [2019-01-24 15:50:29 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:26 +0000,
  #     2019-01-24 15:50:29 +0000]]
```

Each item in the top level array is a Point, each Point has multiple timestamps which it is estimating. Only one timestamp can be used per point however. The objective is to find the value which, when combined with a tolerance (let's say 3 seconds for this example), will contain the most points. The optimal value may not actually be one of the points, in the same way that a straight line on a graph may not touch any points.

I considered using a cartesian to find the average (mean or median) and standard deviation of the data, but this could be slow and still not give me the correct result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, if do you wish to select one timestamp per element (array) of `times`, compute the maximum number of those `times.size` timestamps that are within a given time of each other and then repeat for all other (`times.map(&:size).reduce(:*)-1`) combinations of selections, to find which combination yields the greatest number of timestamps within a given time of each other? If so, you're looking at an NP-hard (combinatorial) problem.

Comment: Readers will not be able to easily reproduce `times` to test their code, since elements (of elements) are `Time` objects. It would be better if you could make those elements strings that readers could convert to time objects. Also, is it really necessary to have such a "large" example?

Comment: Note there are `times.map(&:size).reduce(:*) #=> 754974720` ways of drawing one element from each element of `times`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and your help. Yeah, I'm aware the cartesian (map, reduce) is large, hence why I'd like to avoid it. I'll give an example of what I'm looking for. Given the data above, it _could_ be that `15:50:46 ± 3 seconds` will include a value from all 9 points in the top level array. The optimal value (e.g. 15:50:46) may not be in the list at all. The important bit is that a value from the child array cannot be used/counted more than once. Additionally I'm working in milliseconds, so there are unlikely to be so many identical values. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_hits(times, tolerance)
  coverage = times.map do |a|
    a.each_with_object({}) do |t,h|
      ((t-tolerance).to_i..(t+tolerance).to_i).each { |tt| h[Time.at(tt)] = t }
    end
  end
  min_secs, max_secs = times.flatten.minmax.map(&:to_i)
  min_secs += tolerance
  max_secs -= tolerance
  if min_secs > max_secs
    best = Time.at((min_secs+max_secs)/2)
  else
    best = Time.at((min_secs..max_secs).max_by do |n|
      t = Time.at(n)
      coverage.count { |h| h.key?(t) }
    end)
  end
  [best, coverage.map { |h| h[best] }]
end
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 13, 14].each do |tolerance|
  print "tolerance = #{tolerance} seconds, best = "
  best, a = max_hits(times, tolerance)
  puts "#{best}, count = #{a.compact.size}"
  puts "  #{a}"
end
```

```
tolerance = 0 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, count = 8
  [2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, nil]
tolerance = 1 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, count = 8
  [2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000, nil]
tolerance = 2 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000, count = 8
  [2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:42 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000, nil]
tolerance = 8 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:38 +0000, count = 8
  [2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:42 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:41 +0000, nil]
tolerance = 9 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:37 +0000, count = 9
  [2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:46 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:44 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:42 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:41 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:29 +0000]   
tolerance = 13 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:39 +0000, count = 9
  [2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:51 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:50 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:42 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:41 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:29 +0000]
tolerance = 14 seconds, best = 2019-01-24 15:50:39 +0000, count = 9
  [2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:51 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:50 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:45 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:47 +0000,
   2019-01-24 15:50:42 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:41 +0000, 2019-01-24 15:50:29 +0000]
```

For `tolerance` equal to `0` we see that all elements (arrays) of `times` but the last contain the time `2019-01-24 15:50:46` and that there are no times for which `count` equals `times.size` (`9`). Note that this value of `best` is also optimum for values of tolerance between `1` and `8` (but are different than the values shown as `best`), so there are clearly multiple optima for those values of tolerance.

It can be seen that

```
times.size
  #=> 9 
min_secs, max_secs = times.flatten.minmax.map(&:to_i)
max_secs - min_secs
  #=> 27
```

Therefore, for each of `28-2*tolerance` time values, each of the `9` elements (hashes) of `coverage` would be examined. If times were in milliseconds, this would be `1000*(28-2*tolerance)` time values, an easily-manageable number. Of course, if the range of times and size of `times` were larger (or `tolerance` were smaller), the computational effort would increase accordingly.

One cannot iterate over `Time` objects, which is why I've written, for example,

```
((t-tolerance).to_i..(t+tolerance).to_i).each { |tt| h[Time.at(tt)] = t }
```

rather than

```
  (t-tolerance..t+tolerance).each { |tt| h[tt] = t }
```